# Read output from subprocess without using pipes

Tags: windows, bash, pipe, subprocess, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to run bash.exe (Bash on Ubuntu for Windows) as a build command for Sublime Text. However, bash.exe has a bug and does not support outputting its stdout to any pipe.

Question is this: how can I run a cmd line (i.e. "bash.exe -c ls") and capture the output without ever making bash.exe output into pipes on windows?

I'm open to using any languages or environment on Windows to make this tool.

#### Edit

I ran
`bashTest = subprocess.Popen(["bash.exe", "-c", "ls"]), stdout=subproccess.PIPE)`

Which yielded:

`bashTest.communicate()[0] b'E\x00r\x00r\x00o\x00r\x00:\x00\x000\x00x\x008\x000\x000\x007\x000\x000\x005\x007\x00\r\x00\r\x00\n\x00'`

Comment: You can use a pipe like this:

`echo "hello world" | { read test; echo test=$test; }`
or even write a function like this:

`read_from_pipe() { read "$@" <&0; }`

Comment: The problem is that any time code tries to print bash.exe's output to a pipe, as this [github page](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/2) says, the only information provided is some random error message. Pipes cannot be part of the process at all.

Comment: post the error and your input please

Comment: [Comment moved to main question edit for clarity]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible. There's a [github issue about it](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/2) which was closed as a known limitation. If you want to increase awareness of it, I see 2 related User Voice ideas: [Allow Windows programs to spawn Bash](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/266908-command-prompt-console-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windo/suggestions/13425768-allow-windows-programs-to-spawn-bash) and [Allow native Win32 applications to launch Linux tools/commands](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/266908-command-prompt-console-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windo/suggestions/13250514-allow-native-win32-applications-to-launch-wls-exec).

There are ways you could hack around it, however. One way would be to write a script which loops forever in a bash.exe console. When the script gets a signal, it runs Linux commands with the output piped to a file then signals that it is complete. Here's some pseudo code:

Linux:

```
while true
  while not exists /mnt/c/dobuild
    sleep 1
  end
  gcc foo.c > /mnt/c/build.log
  rm /mnt/c/dobuild
end
```

Windows:

```
touch C:\dobuild
while exists C:\dobuild
  sleep 1
end
cat C:\build.log
```

This does require keeping a bash.exe console always open with the script running, which is not ideal.

Another potential workaround, which was already mentioned, is to use [ReadConsoleOutput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684965(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the option `shell=True in Popen()` to have pipes work.

like this example dont need to split this command.

```
>>> import subprocess as sp    
>>> cmd = 'echo "test" | cat'
>>> process = sp.Popen(cmd,stdout=sp.PIPE,shell=True)
>>> output = process.communicate()[0]
>>> print output
test
```

Comment: Did not change anything, unfortunately.

If you doubt the problem I am having, the [github page](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/2) I mentioned is very clear about the incompatibility. I am looking for some workaround to using pipes.

Comment: you can also redirect to a subshell using process substitution: `command > >(stdlog pipe)  2> >(stderr pipe)`  for  example command `2> >(grep 'something') >/dev/null`

Comment: (http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections)[this address also has info about redirections]

Comment: @khakishoiab: please do note that the question is NOT about the usual bash on Linux, Cygwin and so on, but about WSL.  On the Windows side of WSL, "bash" is not the bash shell proper, it is a launcher that makes certain hocus-pocus resulting in the real bash starting in the "linux" environment, its stdin and stdout piped into the Windows console box. It's complicated,

Answer (score 0):

Your only realistic option, if you can't wait for a fix, would be to use [ReadConsoleOutput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684965(v=vs.85).aspx) and/or the related functions.